# Do similar imports in different java files in Android Studio cause increase in App size?

Tags: java

I have some same type java imports in 4 java files of Android project in Android Studio. Does it make import same file four times and hence increasing application size?

Answer (score 2):

No. `import` statement in Java allows to refer to classes which are declared in other packages to be accessed without referring to the full package name and this is not affecting final binary. That's pretty common that the same class is referenced in various place, but as this is still the same class, there's no point for compiler to multiply it in final binary.

Answer (score 0):

If the import is referring to a class in the Java Platform Library, then no.  When you install the JVM, the binaries for the platform library are already installed to the system.  The import in this case is simply making your code more readable by freeing you from always typing in fully qualified type names.

If the import is referring to a third-party class not in the Java Platform Library, then it may need to be packaged into your JAR or WAR and then, yes, it will increase both the size of your application file and (probably) the size of its memory footprint.